# Azure LogicAPP to Receive data from SAP Message Server (Preview)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, sap-dotnet-connector

Does anybody know how to retrieve data from SAP module using SAP Message Server (Preview) in LogicApp.

I have connected to on premise gateway but not sure how do I call the SAP module from LogicApp. I have tried to google blogs or article for using SAP Message Server (Preview) but couldn't find anything that could explain how can you connect SAP Module with your logic app on azure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bhavesh we are mainly using two way to connect Logic app to SAP

1) BABI 
2) IDOC

Comment: thanks, I am new two this. would you mind listing steps on how you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know how to retrieve data from SAP module using SAP Message Server (Preview) in LogicApp.

You may get the answer from the [Azure official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-sap-connector). The following is the snippet from the document.

> 1.Add the Request/Response trigger, and then select New step.
>
> 2.Select Add an action, and then select the SAP connector by typing SAP in the search field:
>
> 3.Select SAP Application Server or SAP Message Server, based on your SAP setup. If you don't have an existing connection, you are prompted to create one.
>
> 4.Enter a name for your SAP connection
>
> 5.The different SAP options are now available. To find your IDOC category, select from the list. Or manually type in the path, and select the HTTP response in the body field:
>
> 6.Add the action for creating an HTTP Response. The response message should be from the SAP output
>
> 7.Save your logic app. Test it by sending an IDOC through the HTTP trigger URL. After the IDOC is sent, wait for the response from the logic app:

**Note:**

> Current limitations:
>
> - Your logic app times out if all steps required for the response don't finish within the request timeout limit. In this scenario, requests might get blocked.
> - The file picker does not display all the available fields. In this scenario, you can manually add paths.